# Vandermonde matrix where the nodes are primitive roots of unity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N=2^n$ be some power-of-2 and $\omega_1, \dots, \omega_{N/2}$ be the primitive $N$-th roots of unity. That is, for $i = 1, \dots, N/2$, it holds that $\omega_i^{N/2} = -1$. Let $V_N=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & \omega_1 & \dots & \omega^{N/2-1}\\
1 & \omega_2 & \dots & \omega^{N/2-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & \omega_{N/2} & \dots & \omega_{N/2}^{N/2-1}
\end{pmatrix}$ be a Vandermonde matrix with the primitive roots of unity as nodes.
Then what is its operator norm $\|V_N^{-1}\|$ in terms of $N$? The operator norm of an $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ is defined as $\|A\|:= \max_{x\in\mathbb{C}^n}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$.

Let's define the Frobenius norm of a matrix $A$ be $\|A\|_F := \sqrt{\mathrm{Tr}(A^*A)}$. It is known that $\|V_N\|_F = N/2$ and $\|V_N^{-1}\|_F = 1$. And by the fact that $\|A\| \leq \|A\|_F$, we have an upper bound $\|V_N^{-1}\| \leq 1$. I also know a lower bound $\|V_N^{-1}\| \geq 1/\sqrt{N/2}$.

Comment: as hint: (i) you want the (inverse of) the smallest singular value for $V_N$, (ii) show your work for $\big\Vert V_N\big\Vert_F$... in addition to a square root issue, if you show $V_N^*V_N$ you get information for (i)